# PHP Regex for active menu states

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a function that did a check on the page link I passed in and the request URI.

```
function setActiveMenuState($pageLink) {
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ($pageLink == $requestUri) {
        return "active";
    }
}
```

This worked like this:

```
<li class="<?= setActiveMenuState("/find-a-job/"); ?>">
```

This is fine, but I now need to check an active state on a page where the page link can vary.

E.g.

```
find-a-job
find-a-job/jobs/test-job-1
find-a-job/jobs/test-job-2
```

All the above need to set the list element to have the same active state, but this link:

```
find-a-job/about-us
```

Shouldn't set the that list element to active.

I have as an example tried:

```
if (preg_match($pageLink, $requestUri)) {
    return "active";
}
```

But that of course will match every url that has find-a-job.

I need some sort of wildcard approach so find-a-job/jobs/*

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You already have it, with the preg_match use `/find-a-job/jobs/` instead of `/find-a-job/`, it should work

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
preg_match("/find-a-(job)(?:\/\1s.*)?/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK4mY9/2)**